# Get image boundaries across stacked images in 3D array efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to box MNIST images using the col and row wise min and max non zero values for each image. I am able to do that using a for loop but I want to know if it can be done without the loop. Here's some toy data

```
arr = np.array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

For ex. for arr[0] I want to retrieve the non-zero picture boundaries as

`row_min, row_max, col_min, col_max = [1, 3, 1, 3]`

I'm doing this using a for loop as follows and it works

```
for val in arr:
    row_max, col_max = np.apply_along_axis(max,1,np.nonzero(val))
    row_min, col_min = np.apply_along_axis(min,1,np.nonzero(val)) 
    val[row_min:row_max+1,[col_min,col_max]] = 1
    val[[row_min,row_max],col_min:col_max+1] = 1
```

However, I want to avoid the for loop (I currently have the above code in a separate function) and have this transformation inline.

`np.apply_over_axes` is not working for me as np.nonzero doesn't take any axis values. I'm not sure how to just split the array along the first axis (and then proceed to apply `np.apply_along_axis(min,1,np.nonzero(val))` for each of the 2D arrays that we'll have)

Comment: What happens if an image is all zeros?

Comment: interesting - I dint think about it and the image data I have doesn't contain such a case. For an all zero image the code I've written currently boxes at [0,0] so it'll be just one pixel with value 1. I'm cropping and scaling the image to 20x20 in subsequent steps - I guess I'll have to filter out this kind of case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one with `argmax` for efficiency -

```
def get3Dboundaries(arr):
    row_start = arr.any(2).argmax(1)
    row_end = arr.shape[1]-arr.any(2)[:,::-1].argmax(1)-1

    col_start = arr.any(1).argmax(1)
    col_end = arr.shape[2]-arr.any(1)[:,::-1].argmax(1)-1

    return np.c_[row_start,row_end,col_start,col_end]
```

Sample run -

```
In [61]: arr
Out[61]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # different second slice for variety
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]])

In [62]: get3Dboundaries(arr)
Out[62]: 
array([[1, 3, 1, 3],
       [1, 4, 0, 3]])
```

We can make it handle all zeros case with an invalid specifier, say `-1`, like so -

```
def get3Dboundaries_v2(arr):
    row_start = arr.any(2).argmax(1)
    row_end = arr.shape[1]-arr.any(2)[:,::-1].argmax(1)-1

    col_start = arr.any(1).argmax(1)
    col_end = arr.shape[2]-arr.any(1)[:,::-1].argmax(1)-1

    out = np.c_[row_start,row_end,col_start,col_end]
    return np.where(arr.any((1,2))[:,None],out,-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [76]: arr
Out[76]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])

In [78]: get3Dboundaries_v2(arr)
Out[78]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  1,  3],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1]])
```